# Disk usage analyzers freeze in the middle of operation

Tags: disk-usage

14.04

I've been trying not just Baobab that came bundled, but also K4dirstat, Filelight and JDiskReport. I have even tried running WinDirStat under Wine! They all start working, then freeze about halfway through the process.

Any advice?

Edit: Here is [some info on my partitions](http://i208.photobucket.com/albums/bb124/Fiksdal/Screenshot%20from%202015-10-08%20160619.png). The partition I was trying to scan when I got the error was `sda2`. I have booted into Windows 7 and run WinDirStat from there, and there I was able to finish the scan successfully. (So actually, I should probably just go to bed and forget about this whole issue. I'm kinda OCD.)

Here is the output to `sudo smartctl --all /dev/sda`:

```
smartctl 6.2 2013-07-26 r3841 [x86_64-linux-3.13.0-65-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-13, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Device Model:     ST500LT012-1DG142
Serial Number:    S3PB1KVE
LU WWN Device Id: 5 000c50 0752d8c10
Firmware Version: 0001SDM1
User Capacity:    500,107,862,016 bytes [500 GB]
Sector Sizes:     512 bytes logical, 4096 bytes physical
Rotation Rate:    5400 rpm
Device is:        Not in smartctl database [for details use: -P showall]
ATA Version is:   ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.0, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Sun Oct 11 02:21:59 2015 IST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x82) Offline data collection activity
                    was completed without error.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Enabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x7b) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   1) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (  97) minutes.
Conveyance self-test routine
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x1035) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 10
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x000f   106   099   006    Pre-fail  Always       -       10534328
  3 Spin_Up_Time            0x0003   100   099   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  4 Start_Stop_Count        0x0032   098   098   020    Old_age   Always       -       2451
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   036    Pre-fail  Always       -       16
  7 Seek_Error_Rate         0x000f   075   060   030    Pre-fail  Always       -       17312465395
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       2345 (153 159 0)
 10 Spin_Retry_Count        0x0013   100   100   097    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   098   098   020    Old_age   Always       -       2448
184 End-to-End_Error        0x0032   100   100   099    Old_age   Always       -       0
187 Reported_Uncorrect      0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
188 Command_Timeout         0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
189 High_Fly_Writes         0x003a   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0022   058   049   045    Old_age   Always       -       42 (Min/Max 31/45)
191 G-Sense_Error_Rate      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       2375
192 Power-Off_Retract_Count 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       53
193 Load_Cycle_Count        0x0032   098   098   000    Old_age   Always       -       4436
194 Temperature_Celsius     0x0022   042   051   000    Old_age   Always       -       42 (0 22 0 0 0)
197 Current_Pending_Sector  0x0012   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
198 Offline_Uncorrectable   0x0010   100   100   000    Old_age   Offline      -       0
199 UDMA_CRC_Error_Count    0x003e   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
240 Head_Flying_Hours       0x0000   098   098   000    Old_age   Offline      -       100167227279665
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       10919957375
242 Total_LBAs_Read         0x0000   100   253   000    Old_age   Offline      -       23978392682
254 Free_Fall_Sensor        0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Aborted by host               60%       702         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       200         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     32336         -

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

Comment: I've added the output you requested, plus some additional information.

Comment: I booted into Windows and did a check and repair of the disks. After that, some of the tools, like Filelight and GD Map, work. Fine by me. Enough of this. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Patience is a virtue:** First wait long enough for the program to finish if you've got big (or slow) drives as it's analysing all your drives.

Failing that (give it a night), you probably have a file system error on one of your partitions.

So for the Windows partitions, boot into Windows and perform a:

```
CHKDSK /F X:
```

for each partition where `X` is the drive letter of your partitions (probably `C`, `D`, `E` etc..

For the `ext4` partition, boot an Ubuntu LiveDVD and perform a:

```
fsck -C /dev/XdYZ
```

where `X` is `h`or `s` depending on ATA/SCSI drives and `Y` is a letter from `a` to `z` and `Z` is a number. (to see them for your system, type `blkid` on your system)

That should get rid of the file system errors!

Answer (score 0):

These disk usage apps went gray and unresponsive for a while,  but when I just waited through it,  they  eventually came back to life and finished the job. They all gave correct results,  except for K4DirStat, which gave wrong results. I also booted into Windows and did a disk scan and repair, that may also have been what caused the programs to unfreeze in the end.