# How to check what big files are in /home and how to install somewhere else?

Tags: software-installation

i am trying to install matlab and its trying to install in /home because i get a warning saying /home is left with 1 gb. How do I check what folders are in home and how can I install matlab in /dev/sda6 instead because it has 67gb free ?

[image]

Comment: I do not understand "How do I check what folders are in home[?]" Are you asking us how to explain the basic `ls` and/or `du` commands?

Comment: ty. what if my disk usage analyzer hangs then crashes everytime i open it for the folder /home ?

Comment: Comments are intended to help you improve (edit) your question, not for conversation. Please don't bury important information in comments. If Disk Usage Analyzer is crashing (what makes you believe that?), solve that seemingly-unrelated problem first. Possibly relevant: https://askubuntu.com/questions/683914/

Comment: First part of your question is not clear. For the second part of your question [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/313592/how-to-install-applications-to-a-separate-hdd) may help.